# Angular Directive to Directive access

Tags: angularjs

How can I access scope value in first directive controller to second directive controller.

So What I mean is if I have `$scope.Hello= "Hello";` in first directive I want to access this in my second directive controller.

How can I do that. I tried with broadcast but I know that only between parent and child access. Here my scenario is child and child access.

Comment: You should probably set up a service...

Comment: I am using angular Service

Comment: What is your code so far then? Please post it.

Comment: It's just service which call web api

Comment: Is the second directive a child scope (not isolated) of the 1st directive? It's not ideal to assume values will be on the scope, leads to difficult to troubleshoot/modify/maintain code. You want directives to be modular and loosely coupled when possible, that's why many prefer using a service or an isolated scope to pass info between directives/controllers. Try from the link function in the second directive to console.log($scope.Hello) and see if it's there.

Comment: @Ericson578 can you please show a sample code how can i pass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link of first directive, call 2nd directive and pass it as attribute.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
angular.element(document.body).append($compile('<my2ndDirectivehello="' + scope.hello+'"></my2ndDirective'>
};
```

Comment: I want to use pass from first controller and then use in second controller

Comment: If you have to pass values from one controller to another, then you can directly use angular service.
Search for controller to controller communication using angular services